# python: how to auto run though code picking all options for a set of three lists to generate all perutations

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i've written some code that generates a product code when u enter its details (code is at the bottem) but i now need it to run though the 3 lists and and use all their results the generate all the possible codes and print them out. any help?

```
count = 1
convert_door_colour = {
    "blue" : "001",
    "black" : "002",
    "red" : "003",
    "green" : "004",
    "white" :"005"
}
convert_door_size = {
    "extra small" : "001",
    "small" : "002",
    "medium": "003",
    "large" : "004",
    "extra large" : "005"
}
convert_number_doors = {
    "1" : "01",
    "2" : "02",
    "3" : "03",
    "4" : "04",
    "5" : "05",
    "6" : "06",
    "7" : "07",
    "8" : "08",
    "9" : "09",
    "10" : "10"
}
run ="1"
while run == "1":
    number_doors = input("how many doors does it have:\n")
    door_order = input("input the order of the doors (type non-glass, glass-a or glass-b:\n")
    door_size = input("what size are the doors:\n")
    door_colour = input("what colour are the doors:\n")
    number_doors_code = (convert_number_doors[number_doors])
    door_colour_code = (convert_door_colour[door_colour])
    door_size_code = (convert_door_size[door_size])
    door_order_code = door_order.replace ('non-glass','0')
    door_order_code = door_order_code.replace ('glass-a','1')
    door_order_code = door_order_code.replace ('glass-b','2')
    door_order_code = door_order_code.replace (' ','')
    product_code = (number_doors_code+door_order_code+door_size_code+door_colour_code)
    print ("the product code is:\n",product_code)
    run_again = input ("do u want to generate another code?\n")
    if run_again == "yes":
        run = "1"
    else:
        run = "2"
print ("thx for using this code :)")
```

Comment: are you looking for this? https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 0):

The number of permutations is list1.length * list2.length * list3.length.
Think of this as a weird number with a different base for each column. So, given a number N, N % list1.length is the index into list1. (N / list1.length) % list2.length is the index into list 2, in effect chopping off the lower digits and extracting the digits we're interested in. Finally, using the same technique, (N / (list2.length * list1.length) % list3.length) is the index into list3.

I'd advise you to pre-calculate any values you can outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product

possible_codes = list(product(convert_door_colour, convert_door_size, convert_number_doors))
print(possible_codes)
```

Something like the above should work. Please note that your data structures are not lists - they're dictionaries with key, value pairs.

Assuming you're wanting permutations of the values,

```
from itertools import product

door_colours = {
    "blue": "001",
    "black": "002",
    "red": "003",
    "green": "004",
    "white": "005"
}
door_sizes = {
    "extra small": "001",
    "small": "002",
    "medium": "003",
    "large": "004",
    "extra large": "005"
}
number_of_doors = {
    "1": "01",
    "2": "02",
    "3": "03",
    "4": "04",
    "5": "05",
    "6": "06",
    "7": "07",
    "8": "08",
    "9": "09",
    "10": "10"
}
possible_codes = []
for colour, size, number in product(door_colours.values(), door_sizes.values(), number_of_doors.values()):
    possible_codes.append('{}{}{}'.format(colour, size, number))
print(possible_codes)
```

this results in an output like:

```
['00100101', '00100102', '00100103', '00100104', '00100105', '00100106', '00100107', ...
```

Comment: that's actually really close thx, the only bit missing is that it needs to also be able to go though all the different orders of 1,2,3,4...,9,10 (i.e. for 5 doors if 1= glass and 0= no glass; 1,1,1,0,0) doors and have that in the codes it produces. Other than that though that's great thx